# My rails app launched with dokku fails at all times (DigitalOcean)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, production-environment, dokku

I have a rail application deployed with dokku and every day I have this error, "We're sorry, but something went wrong". Restart dekku with "dekku ps: restart app" and return to normal but after a while the same error comes back, thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the log files? It's very likely they will point you at what's wrong.

Comment: This error in the logs, "A server is already running. Check /app/tmp/pids/server.pid"

Comment: You will likely need to look back further. If your server is crashed, or some process is killing it off (over memory limit maybe), it may leave behind that pid file, preventing you from re-starting the server process. If you scroll through your logs, you'll probably find either a long stacktrace that caused the crash, or something similar that kills the process.

Comment: Show your Dockerfile or Procfile, and check your Droplet mem and cpu limits, maybe you have too much Dokkus running...